# Increase speed on mysql xammp server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, innodb

I have a production application which uses barcode. It's created using `PHP/MySQL` on xampp server. When there is more than `50000 data` on specific 5 tables then its performance slow on input and fetch data. I have already use indexing on columns. Here are more than 50 users, and give input to 15 users. Its installed on vmware with 14 GB ram and xenon processor server.[pc config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgSGj.jpg)[xampp config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGK3d.jpg)Now I want to increase innodb_buffer_pool_size.Now it's 2G. But if I increase it 3G or above then my MySQL stop unexpectedly. Can anyone give me solution how can I increase it

Comment: Please try this command SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size='size in bytes';

Comment: Thanks. i already change it on my.ini file,  innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G.But if its 3G or above then occurs problem.You want to say write this 'SET GLOBAL' before innodb_buffer_pool_size and convert it from 3G to 3145728

Comment: Please read this may this will helpful for you https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/06/02/80-ram-tune-innodb_buffer_pool_size/

Comment: @MushfequrRahman - `3145728` is only 3MB, _much_ too small for the buffer_pool.

Comment: @MushfequrRahman - 50K rows is "small".  Let's see the query that is slow.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Ahh,thats my mistake,thats not 3 mb,thats 3G